# How Cabal can be configured to use target-prefixed readelf executable

Tags: ghc, cabal, cabal-install

When I do `cabal build` second time I get:

```
readelf: readProcessWithExitCode: runInteractiveProcess: exec: does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

From `strace` I confirmed that it looks for `readelf` executable which on my system have target prefix and look like `x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-readelf`.

Is there any way to configure Cabal and/or GHC to look for specific location of `readelf`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such way at the moment. But with https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/10974 we'll get `-pgmreadelf`.